# ExtJs - Override css in mixins scss

Tags: css, extjs

How can I override the css for this? Basically I want to remove the border of the splitter after focus. I could easily set the **border: none !important** in all.scss in my own theme. But it seems not elegant, I am wondering how to override it properly so that in the built css, the border part of the following css style will be overridden.

```
 /*
 D:/Projects/gui/ext/classic/theme-base/sass/etc/mixins/css-outline.scss:40
 */ 
.x-splitter-focus:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: ' ';
     top: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     border: 2px solid #fff;
     pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: The sencha forum has died. :( No one answering question there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a more specific CSS rule like this:

```
<div class="withoutBorder x-splitter-focus">/div>

.x-splitter-focus:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: ' ';
     top: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     border: 2px solid #fff;
     pointer-events: none; 
}

.withoutBorder.x-splitter-focus:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: ' ';
     top: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     border: none;
     pointer-events: none; 
}
```

In this sample that div wil not have border cause the second rule css is more specific, so, all element with `x-splitter-focus` and `withoutBorder` class will have no border

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. But actually I am looking for answer from ExtJS theming POV. I wonder how to modify the ExtJS theme scss